Help identifying hall effect sensor / guessing replacement from application
I'm trying to find a suitable replacement for a hall effect sensor in a WM9290 CPAP motor ( a brushless turbine ran with a controller board ). It's a SIP3 package and it's markings are
173
539G
I can't find any datasheet online, so i'm trying to learn what the most likely type of sensor for this application is or what the controller board expects, to see what i can get locally. Thanks beforehand!
Edit: based on further reading, what i'm looking for is a bipolar latch hall effect sensor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It will likely be AH173-PG-B-B from Diodes Inc. A latching Hall effect sensor.
From the datasheet, it has the following marking for it's SIP3 package:

The 173 539G marking you report would follow this format.
This part is now obsolete. From the datasheet linked above, it would seem that AH3782-P-A is the manufacturers recommended replacement. The datasheet for that replacement part also says it is obsolete though they are still available. In turn that parts datasheet links to AH3724A-P-B as the recommended replacement.
You would have to compare the differences between AH173-PG-B and either AH3782-P-A or AH3724A-P-B to be sure if they meet your needs. Bit from a cursory glance they look compatible.

i went on to do some reading about types of hall sensors and then removed one of the working ones from the board and ran some tests on it, which determined it was bipolar and latching. I ordered some of this type and i'm hopeful they'll work for the application. Thanks!
